# Animate image view current position to top - left corner

Tags: android

I have Relative layout, in that layout I have image views which altogether looks like one image. I want animate the 6 image views. 3 are `right_top,right_center,right_bottom` and another 3 are `left-top,left-center,left-bottom`. and all these are within its parent layout only...

I want to implement exactly like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIFa7.png).

Comment: do you want to animate all that 6 small images ??

Comment: The question seems like how to  animate the six pieces into one entity,if unnecessary to interact with user ,just use ```TranslateAnimation``` to move to    calculated the position of each piece .

Comment: can u have any example code to animate like i mention in image  @NilDroid

Comment: Use Translate animation. Show your code

Comment: if i use translate animation how to handle the on touch listeners for image views

Comment: then you should use ```propertyAnimation```,```viewAnimation``` is just moved in your eyes ,the object is still in the original position...@siddhu

Answer (score 1):

Hope [**THIS**](https://harinathandroid1.wordpress.com/2012/07/20/toprightleftbottom/) may help you.

And if you want to add scaling to tour animation add this scale inside your each animation set

```
<scale
            android:fromYScale="1.0"
            android:toYScale="0.5"
            android:startOffset="0"
            android:duration="1200"
            android:fromXScale="1.0"
            android:toXScale="0.5"
            android:fillAfter="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

siddhu,sorry for late.

```
  @Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    TranslateAnimation mAnimation1 = new TranslateAnimation(0, mImageViewX.getX(),
            mImageView1.getY(), mImageViewX.getY());
    mAnimation1.setDuration(500);
    mAnimation1.setFillAfter(true);
    mImageView1.startAnimation(mAnimation1);

    TranslateAnimation mAnimation2 = new TranslateAnimation(0,
            - mImageViewX.getX(), mImageView2.getY(), mImageViewX.getY());
    mAnimation2.setDuration(500);
    mAnimation2.setFillAfter(true);
    mImageView2.startAnimation(mAnimation2);

    TranslateAnimation mAnimation3 = new TranslateAnimation(0, mImageViewX.getX(),
            mImageView3.getX(), -mImageViewX.getY());
    mAnimation3.setDuration(500);
    mAnimation3.setFillAfter(true);
    mImageView3.startAnimation(mAnimation3);

}
```

The xml is this :

[image]
[image]

you should learn `animation` first..it's not hard.
`android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation.TranslateAnimation(float fromXDelta, float toXDelta, float fromYDelta, float toYDelta)`
```

Comment: @siddhu so have you make it? if yes you can accept my post to close this question :)

Comment: no man @ i am still get problem when design for multiple screens

Comment: it is suggested to update this question in a more detailed way then all the community can give you a hand  : ) @siddhu

Comment: soory for late i tried this one it works fine but how to handle the on touch listeners for animated images

Comment: You should use `propertyAnimation` instead as i posted right under your question @Nov 20 at 9:53.
But i have a question then,the animation plays in seconds ,how could you do touch matters,it's so quick ! if you wanna do that right after the animation,i.e the combined image interact with user, simply put one overlay  view over the combined image and set it's alpha 0,then you can not see it but you can respond to the touch or click matters.@siddhu